# Descarga archivos(varios) en Base64 con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, base64

Actualmente estoy descargando PDF desde Base64 en Java usando JS, pero quisiera saber si puedo en la misma función descargar cualquier archivo que no sea solo PDF ??

```
function generaDescargablePdf(data, name){
    var arrBuffer = base64ToArrayBuffer(data);

    // It is necessary to create a new blob object with mime-type explicitly set
    // otherwise only Chrome works like it should
    var newBlob = new Blob([arrBuffer], { type: "application/pdf" });

    // IE doesn't allow using a blob object directly as link href
    // instead it is necessary to use msSaveOrOpenBlob
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob);
        return;
    }

    // For other browsers: 
    // Create a link pointing to the ObjectURL containing the blob.
    var data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);

    var link = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(link); //required in FF, optional for Chrome
    link.href = data;
    link.download = name;
    link.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
    link.remove();
}
```

Existirá alguna manera de poder descargar Excel, JPG, PDF, DOC desde Base64 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código funciona bien, puedes obtener la descarga de cualquier tipo de archivo solamente cambiando el MIME ([Aquí puedes encontrar una lista](https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/)). Dejo una pequeña captura de la página:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo:

```
// Es suficiente cambiando ésta linea de código
var newBlob = new Blob([arrBuffer], { type: "application/pdf" });

// Si quieres descargar una imagen PNG
var newBlob = new Blob([arrBuffer], { type: "image/png" });

// Si quieres descargar un archivo de texto
var newBlob = new Blob([arrBuffer], { type: "text/plain" });
```

Ahora bien si lo que quieres es descargar cualquier archivo de forma dinámica lo que podrías hacer es verificar si la cadena base64 tiene una estructura de la siguiente forma:

> data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhDAAMAKIFAF5LAP/zxAAAANyuAP/gaP///wAAAAAA...

En este caso si pones atención a `data:image/png`, éste ya te dice el mime que debes utilizar, lo único que queda por hacer es limpiar esa cadena para que solo quede el mime.

Algo así, **(OJO que esto solo es un ejemplo sencillo y me queda claro que puede haber otras formas más óptimas de hacerlo)**:

```
var arrdata = data.split(',');
var fileBase64 = arrdata[1];
var mime = arrdata[0].replace('data:', '').replace(';base64', '');
```

Quedando el código completo de la siguiente manera:

```
function generaDescargablePdf(data, name){
    var arrdata = data.split(',');
    var fileBase64 = arrdata[1];
    var mime = arrdata[0].replace('data:', '').replace(';base64', '');
    var arrBuffer = base64ToArrayBuffer(fileBase64 );

    // It is necessary to create a new blob object with mime-type explicitly set
    // otherwise only Chrome works like it should
    var newBlob = new Blob([arrBuffer], { type: mime });

    // IE doesn't allow using a blob object directly as link href
    // instead it is necessary to use msSaveOrOpenBlob
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob);
        return;
    }

    // For other browsers: 
    // Create a link pointing to the ObjectURL containing the blob.
    var data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);

    var link = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(link); //required in FF, optional for Chrome
    link.href = data;
    link.download = name;
    link.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
    link.remove();
}
```

Bueno lo mas sencillo que podrias hacer en el caso de que tengas el **nombre y la extensión** del archivo es lo siguiente:

```
function generaDescargablePdf(data, name){
    var arrBuffer = base64ToArrayBuffer(data);

    // It is necessary to create a new blob object with mime-type explicitly set
    // otherwise only Chrome works like it should
    var newBlob = new Blob([arrBuffer]);

    // IE doesn't allow using a blob object directly as link href
    // instead it is necessary to use msSaveOrOpenBlob
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob);
        return;
    }

    // For other browsers: 
    // Create a link pointing to the ObjectURL containing the blob.
    var data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);

    var link = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(link); //required in FF, optional for Chrome
    link.href = data;
    link.download = name;
    link.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
    link.remove();
}
```

Como notas quité el mime pero en este caso la variable `name` debe tener la extensión del archivo también, de otra forma no funcionará.

Comment: Pero es posible descargar cualquiera de las 3 sin tener que hacer funcion para cada una ? 
algo así como var newBlob = new Blob([arrBuffer], { type: "application/pdf" } , { type: "image/png" } , { type: "text/plain" });

Comment: Modifiqué la respuesta, espero que de alguna manera te de una idea de lo que podrías hacer ;)

Comment: Creo que sin usar el mime siempre y cuando tengas la extensión del archivo te funcionará bien ;)

Answer (score 0):

estoy probando con algo similar pero en el caso de ser un archivo que no siga esta estructura:

data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhDAAMAKIFAF5LAP/zxAAAANyuAP/gaP///wAAAAAA...

simplemente R0lGODlhDAAMAKIFAF5LAP/zxAAAANyuAP/gaP///wAAAAAA...
como se puede obtener la extensión del archivo, hay alguna forma?

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/327657)